# Bing news search API Json response url param

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api, bing-news-search-api

Today in the Bing the news search API response Json, I found that the url parameter is coming in a different way then it was coming previously.

As per the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Bing-News-Search/quickstart#the-response

The url parameter should start with

"url" : "http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=CCE2F06CA.......www.abc.com/......"

But since today it is starting with

"url" : "www abc.com......"

It is omitting the "bing.com...." prefixes..

Please confirm if this was changed recently and any plans to support the original one ??

Answer (score 0):

> Please confirm if this was changed recently and any plans to support the original one .

It seems that it is changed recently. We could check the [document history](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/ac8d0560e9734a214d80eb44476368471d8fb38e#diff-8c53779080f6512eb654eac37fe5716e) from GitHub.

Based on my experience, it seems that there is no  plan to support the original one.

But I also recommend that you could report an [Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get the help from Azure team directly.